# Uploading a file in selenium/golang

Tags: selenium, go, file-upload, automated-tests

I'm trying to automate a test where I need to upload a file, but I keep getting that the file can't be found.
I found in Selenium page that, for other languages, we have to use a Local File Detector so that the file that's in my computer are sent to the remote server.

> The Local File Detector allows the transfer of files from the client machine to the remote server.

But I can't find any function related to that in Go.

I've tried the SendKeys function:

```
    element, err := crediya.el.FindElement(selenium.ByID, "file")
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf(errors.Selenium.ElementNotFound+"\n%w", err)
    }

    if err = element.SendKeys(path); err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf(errors.Selenium.SendKeysFailure+"\n%w", err)
    }
```

but I keep getting:

"unknown error - 61: invalid argument: File not found : "

Note: the element is an input of file type.

Thank you, in advance, for any help provided.

Can someone, please, help me?

Comment: are you sure `path` is set to something?  `...File not found : "` makes it sound like the filename is empty

Comment: I've tried to send the relative path and the full path. For what I read I believe that I have to send the file to the selenium server and then send that path to send keys.

Comment: Ensure that the file path you're passing to the SendKeys method is correct and the file exists. You can use the os.Stat function to verify if the file exists and you have permission to access it.

_, err := os.Stat(path)
if os.IsNotExist(err) {
    return fmt.Errorf("File not found: %s", path)
}

Comment: Thank you for all your help. I've managed to solve the problem. Using docker + selenium, I had to upload the file to the selenium server, save it in a folder there and, then, pass the path of the file in the server (not my local path).

Answer (score 0):

The fact is that the tebeka/selenium library was written 12 years ago. The last commit was made two years ago.

I have forked the repository and refined this function!

```
go get github.com/la4zen/selenium
```

This function working ONLY with remote connection to selenium.

```
import (
    "github.com/la4zen/selenium"
)

func main() {
    s := selenium.NewRemote(...)
    directory, err := s.UploadFiles('/path/to/file')
    if err != nil {
       panic("nil value")
    }
    fmt.Println(directory) // directory in selenium session
}
```

Next, you can use this for fill input type=file

```
element, err := s.FindElement("input")  // Don't forget to check error!
element.SendKeys(directory+"/path/to/file") // Path used in function uploadFiles
```